# Gaussian16 Raman calculation from IR checkpoint file

Tags: theoretical-chemistry, software, density-functional-theory

I already did an IR frequency calculation for my molecule. Is there any possibility to just run a Raman frequency calculation with the `chk` file from my IR calculation?

Or do I have to do the calculation again with the `freq=raman` keyword? I checked the Gaussian manual and found the `raman=polar` keyword, but I think this is not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Related (unanswered) question on [researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can-anyone-help-with-separate-frequency-and-Raman-computations-in-Gaussian-09). The paper mentioned suggests it was possible in Gaussian09, so there should be a keyword for this. A combination of `freq=SaveNormalModes` in the frequency calculation and `freq=ReadNormalModes` in the Raman calculation may do the trick, but I haven't gotten a chance to test it.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it today and will report later how it worked.

Comment: @Tyberius @Andrea I tried it with the keywords `freq=SaveNormalModes`and `freq=ReadNormalModes`. I used Methanol as an easy example. 
First I run an optimization followed by a normal frequency calculation by using the geom=allcheck and the suggested `freq=SaveNormalModes` keywords. The last calculation a raman with this Routesection
`%chk=methanol_raman.chk
%oldchk=methanol_freq.chk
#p GFINPUT POP(FULL,NBO) B3LYP/6-31G(d,p) freq=(raman,ReadNormalModes) geom=check`
The calculation ends with the error `FileIO operation on non-existent file.`.

Answer (score 2):

Raman intensities require polarizabilities to be calculated, IR intensities only dipole moments. Your checkpoint file may therefore not have the properties you require, in which case you'll need to do more calculations. Using the `polar=raman` keyword would apparently save you a little bit of time, because the program then already knows your force constants and normal modes from the preceding `freq` calculation, but there will still be computational effort involved in calculating the polarizabilities.

Note that there are some cases where Gaussian also give you the polarizabilities "for free", as the manual states on the `polar=raman` page:

> Note that Polar is done by default when second derivatives are computed analytically.

You can use the `chkchk` tool to see what's really stored in the checkpoint file.